# Can't install angular material (getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, proxy, angular-material

I tried to run `ng add @angular/material` inside my angular project, but got this error:

*Unable to fetch package metadata: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fmaterial failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.{companyname}.interno* (I hid my company name)

The answers I found are about the proxy settings, but my company is using no proxy for six months.

If I run `netsh winhttp show proxy` on cmd it says I have no proxy.
If i run `npm config get proxy` it returns null.

I tried:

- Removing my environment variables about proxy (I had none, no http_proxy or https_proxy)
- Running `npm config delete proxy` / `npm config rm https-proxy` / `npm config rm http-proxy` / `npm config rm proxy` (just for the sake of it, since as I said, get proxy returns null)
- Running `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org`
- Going to my regedit on Internet Settings and disabling ProxyEnable, MigrateProxy and ProxyOverride
- Setting strict-ssl to false

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED IT**

It was a problem about having two HDs! Node was installed on C:/ and my projects were on D:/

Every change I did via powershell altered the C:/ files. There was a .npmrc on my D:/ that was overriding those changes. Deleting it made it work.

Well, guess that's something that can happen when you bring tools that were thought for linux into a windows world :P